# Webviewer In Filemaker WebDirect

Tags: web, url, filemaker

My webviewer works perfectly in FM Pro Adv, but I have assigned my solution to a URL, which works as expected, my problem is now the Web Viewer doesn't display in the page when using Web Direct.

I'm trying to display Instagram pages, the protocol for the Instagram website its HTTPS, but my URL that I use to display me Web Direct solution is unsecured.

Is this whats causing the issue? If so is there a simple fix? I've been doing alot of reading but the only workarounds I can see are very heavy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, most browsers will block iframe content that does not match the parent protocol because of a mixed-content violation. As WebDirect is served in an iframe container in browsers, this is the expected result.

You need to set up your web server with an SSL certificate and serve your page using HTTPS. Many hosting providers have this option in their control panel or you may have to roll your own solution.

Comment: Andreas coming through with the goods again. Thankyou, looks like I'm paying for some SSL!

Comment: Whilst I have you Andreas, would this also be the case for Container fields? As I thought I could at least display a container field via WebDirect without any issues but that doesn't seem to be the case.

I have a layout with 6 global container fields, all populated with an images, all displaying perfectly in FM Pro Adv, but as soon as I launch FM WD, they are all empty. This is extremely painful, im beginning to wonder if this Web Direct is worth the trouble.

Comment: Happy to be of assistance. Yes, any content will be blocked which is served with a non-matching protocol.

Comment: Actually I may have misread your comment about container fields. I connected it to use in WebDirect and I suppose that's not what you meant. Container fields on a regular FileMaker layout should work as normal in WebDirect so that is a separate issue.